# Flutter VSC Menu Button dissapeared

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have some troubles with my Flutter project. My Menu button, disappeared. When I open a new "tab" there is only the possibility to go back, but not to open the Navigation.

I think the issue might be here:

```
 Widget _buildAndroid(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(DokumenteTab.title),
  ),
  body: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(child: _buildDocumentList()),
      FloatingActionButton(
        //Button aufruf
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Maby someone else can help me.

Greets

Comment: Umm... Where have u defined the menu button?

Comment: Also, why have ya given the FloatingActionButton inside a Column?

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted your question correctly, your FAB is the "Menu" Button...?

The Scaffold Widget has it's own property for displaying the floatingActionButton, just look at the starter project:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Button pressed $_counter times'),
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Counter to Zero'), onPressed: _counterToZero),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _incrementCounter,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  );
}
```